# How to simplify the query output?

Tags: mysql

The below query result is the result of mysql query which i have executed against database table. It returns same value more than one time.

**query result**

```
name     section     role
----------------------------
abc         A        Manager
abc         B        Ass Manager
abc         A        Clark
abc         B        Engineer
abc         A        Manager
```

How can i simplify the output like below table.

**simplified output**

```
name     section     role
----------------------------
abc         A        Manager
            B        Ass Manager
                     Clark
                     Engineer
```

Is this possible with mysql query. If not kindly help me if any other option is available? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;`

Comment: `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` may help you to get something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get non-repeating data of a column if it has less rows than other columns. If you want to get all distinct data of a column, you should select each one individually.

But that's only a visual simplification. You can handle the data on your code quite easily by filtering the repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the output is not a valid result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abfcb0/1) online test.

```
SELECT `name`, `section`, GROUP_CONCAT(`role`) FROM janaki GROUP BY `name`, `section`

name     section     GROUP_CONCAT(`role`)
-----------------------------------------
abc        A         Manager,Clark,Manager
abc        B         Ass Manager,Engineer
```

Straight query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name`, `section`, `role` FROM janaki


name       section       role     
-------------------------------
abc        A             Manager
abc        B             Ass Manager
abc        A             Clark
abc        B             Engineer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use tools like Pentaho or BIRT which are designed to generate good looking reports from such data.